# autosys monthy job for seventh businessdate

Tags: calendar, autosys, monthcalendar, jil

I have below requirement for autosys calendar.

the autosys job should be triggered only once in a month on every 7th business date (exclude weekends).

*for example*, in the month of May 2021, the job should run on 11 May 2021.
In the month of May 2021 as 01, 02 & 08, 09 are weekends, thus the job should consider 11th May 2021 as the 7th business day of the month to trigger the job.
Next it should run on 09th of June 2021.

~ Thank you!

Comment: This can be done by "extended calendar", try to refer to Autosys Manual and give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHnv.jpg) Build an Extended calendar using the Condition: WORKD#07

See my screenshot of what I built for the 6th work day.